# Get HTML Current Page name alone, followed by ".htm" from URL or Pathname using Jquery & Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Scenario like: Below,

Following a "Menu List" having href value set to corresponding ".htm" Pages inside "Menu.html"

1. Click Me to got to pageOne.htm
2. Click Me to got to pageTwo.htm
3. Click Me to got to pageThree.htm
4. Click Me to got to pageFour.htm

Each Pages pageOne.htm, pageTwo.htm & pageThree.htm etc.. are having footer part, In footer it must be like it has to contain 3 Links with href values.

I require a solution:
If my Current page is pageOne.htm the Footer should show me shortcuts links to pageTwo.htm, pageThree.htm and pageFour.htm and wise verse depending on my current page.

So I require code to Get .htm from URL pathname.

Can we find() method of Jquery after getting the URL PATH like find(".htm") from URL.

Require just a snippet of Code to get the .htm page name alone.

Including an sample case below:

What if the Url is Like >> 
"http://<10.10.21.26:9080>/myTestAoo/pageThree.htm#detailView"

I wish to get the value "pageThree.htm" alone from above url, if its the current page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you're working with right now. Without knowing what code you use, and what exact working scenarios you'd be using (give us examples of code to work with too), we can't do much to help you.

Comment: This would rather be easy if you're going to show us your CODE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastPartOfUrl = document.URL.split('/').pop();
```

Or with regular expression:

```
var regexp = /([^\/]+)(.htm)/;
var match = regexp.exec(document.URL);
console.log(match[0]); // pageThree.htm
console.log(match[1]); // pageThree
console.log(match[2]); // .htm
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response,What if the Url is Like >> "http://<10.10.21.26>:9080/myTestAoo/pageThree.htm#detailView"; can you please suggest.

Comment: thanks... for the response. It definitely serves my purpose.

I hope using the above regexp, i can reuse it substituting with other extension too. Like eg: /([^\/]+)(.jsp)/ etc.. for other purpose similar to that of this

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the current URL, which you can tidy up using `replace()`:

`window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

you may try this code:

```
var a = window.location.href; 
var fileName = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(fileName);
```

Comment: What if the Url is Like >> "http://<10.10.21.26:9080>/myTestAoo/pageThree.htm#detailView"

I wish to get the value "pageThree.htm" alone from above url, if its the current page.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.pathname`; will returns the full path

try following function

```
function getFileName(){
        var url = window.location.pathname; 
        var path=url.split("/"); 
        var filname=path[path.length-1];
        return filname;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response, Its a good suggestion.

What if the Url is Like >> 
"http://10.10.21.26:9080/myTestAoo/pageThree.htm#detailView"

can you please suggest.